# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append_text'

Tags: python, combobox, glade, python-object

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
class Handler:
    def button_is_clicked(self, button):
        ouraboutwindow.run()
        ouraboutwindow.hide()
    def enter_button_clicked(self, button):
        print ourentry.get_text() + ourcomboboxtext.get_active_text()
builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("ui.glade")
builder.connect_signals(Handler())
ournewbutton = builder.get_object("button1")
window = builder.get_object("window1")
ourcomboboxtext = builder.get_object("comboboxtext1")
default_text = [" World ", " Earth ", " All "]
for x in default_text:
    ourcomboboxtext.append_text(x)
ourcomboboxtext.set_active(0)
ourentry = builder.get_object("entry1")
ourentry.set_max_length(15)
ourentry.set_placeholder_text("Enter A Text Here..")
ouraboutwindow = builder.get_object("aboutdialog1")
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main
```

I am trying to learn the widgets in glade interface where in i have created a text entry a combobox and a button. But the combobox is giving me some error.

Here i will type something in text entry then select something from combobox and together it will be printed in the shell.
Please help.

Comment: `ourcomboboxtext` is `None`, meaning that `builder.get_object("comboboxtext1")` failed to get the combo box.

Comment: got my error @poke

Answer (score 0):

```
ourcomboboxtext = builder.get_object("comboboxtext1")
```

This code depends on glade.
You are following https://www.tecmint.com/create-more-advance-gui-applications-in-linux/.
Choose `comboboxtext1` instead of `combobox1` in glade.